# Jquery effects with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, dhtml

OK, I am missing something fundamental here I am sure! But for the life of me can not work it out.

## Scenario

It's a simple hide show menu;

```
// Setup hover
        var fadeDuration = 200;
        var setDelay;
        $level1Item.hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeOut(fadeDuration);
        });
```

And it works fine... but the drop down is rather LARGE and is irritating when it pops up all be it very sexily when you mouse moves from top to bottom of screen.

So I want to set a timeout and clear it on mouse out...

```
// Setup hover
        var fadeDuration = 200;
        var setDelay;
        $level1Item.hover(function () {
            setDelay = setTimeout("$(this).addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(200)", 500);
            //$(this).addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
        }, function () {
            clearTimeout(setDelay);
            $(this).removeClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeOut(fadeDuration);
        });
```

ABSOLUTELY NOTHING HAPPENS!! I have tried alerts in the timeout function and they work... originally the variable fadeDuration was undefined but a number stops the console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` in the `setTimeout`-code, since `this` depends on the context. So when the timeout fires, the `this` is a different `this`... bad English, but hopefully it makes sense.

Also, avoid using strings in timers; use functions instead. While you *can* use a string, which is then evaluated as JavaScript, it's generally bad form compared to simply wrapping the same code in a function

```
var fadeDuration = 200;
var setDelay;
$level1Item.hover(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    setDelay = setTimeout(function() {
        element.addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(setDelay);
    $(this).removeClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeOut(fadeDuration);
});
```

Comment: Cheers Flambino... very helpful advice, makes total sense.

I tried a function in the setTimout() BUT it was the $(this) that was not working, couldn't get passed  in my head why it wasn't hitting in the function, didn't think to question the $(this).

Answer (score 3):

Try amending the `setTimeout` call to use an anonymous function:

```
// Setup hover
var fadeDuration = 200;
var setDelay;
var $item;

$level1Item.hover(function () {
    $item = $(this);
    setDelay = setTimeout(function() { 
        $item.addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(200)
    }, 500);
}, 
function () {
    clearTimeout(setDelay);
    $(this).removeClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeOut(fadeDuration);
});
```

Comment: Why are you scoping `$item` that far out?

Comment: Thanks Rory! Like I said probably a fundamental mistake, though declaring item in the hover.

I tried a function in the setTimout() BUT it was the $(this) that was not working.

Answer (score 2):

When the string you pass to `setTimeout` is `eval()`ed, `this` is `window` and not whatever object you are expecting.

Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, and be careful to preserve the value of `this`.

```
var self = this;
setDelay = setTimeout(function () { 
                          $(self).addClass('hover').find('.level-2').fadeIn(200);
                      }, 500);
```